# How to resolve iOS SSO Auth failure with 1000 code?

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, single-sign-on

I am going to implement SSO Auth to our enterprise application. I watched [this WWDC talk](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/tech-talks/301/). There is not enough information. I tried to use a simple code from this talk like this:

```
let url = URL(string: "realm://{{identity_server_url}")! //I checked this by changing realm: to https:.
let ssoProvider = ASAuthorizationSingleSignOnProvider(identityProvider: url)
let request = ssoProvider.createRequest()
request.requestedOperation = .operationLogin
let authController = ASAuthorizationController(authorizationRequests: [request])
authController.delegate = self
authController.presentationContextProvider = self
authController.performRequests()

self.ssoProvider = ssoProvider
self.authController = authController
```

But this is always failed with this error description:

```
Error Domain=com.apple.AuthenticationServices.AuthorizationError Code=1000 "(null)"
```

Comment: There is a lot of setup you need to do before you can use this code. Have you installed an SSO extension as part of some other app? Is your device managed by MDM?  Are you using a challenge/response SSO system like Kerberos?  Is enterprise sso actually what you are looking for or do you simply want OAuth authentication against some directory service like Azure AD or Okta?

Comment: Paulw11 thanks for your answer. I have made only an Authentication Services target. SSO is is working now in web frontend with Okta. I installed Okta Verfy to the device also. About other configurations I confused. I couldn't find enough documentation over network. Could you guide me about setup these configurations?

Comment: https://help.okta.com/oie/en-us/Content/Topics/identity-engine/devices/config-credential-sso-ext-ios.htm

Comment: Once you have done that you need to invoke a signin request to your okta domain. The sso extension should intercept the request and return the result without needing to actually open the okta client

Comment: @Paulw11 I have done all setup that you mentioned. But when I try to invoke a signing request to my Okta domain, it is still returning error with code 1000. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Have you added the right management payloads to your device management profile?

Comment: I have done all steps on this article: https://help.okta.com/oie/en-us/Content/Topics/identity-engine/devices/config-credential-sso-ext-ios.htm

Comment: @Paulw11 it is failed with code 1000 and also logged with this error:
[SOConfigurationClient] not AppSSO URL: https://my_url in (
    "{\n    BundleIdentifier = \"okta-bundle\";\n    DeniedBundleIdentifiers = \"<null>\";\n    Hosts =     (\n        \"my_url\"\n    );\n    Realm = \"Okta Device\";\n    ScreenLockedBehavior = Cancel;\n    Type = Credential;\n    URLPrefix = \"<null>\";\n}"
)